# ¿Como utlizar un path de un archivo para cargarlo en una variable en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy haciendo una pagina web y quiero que tome siempre un txt que tengo en la carpeta raiz y lo cargue en una variable para despues manipular los datos de ese txt sin tener que cargarlo con un control input. Que este la ruta siempre fija y que sea lo primero que haga al cargar la pagina

Comment: que tiene ese txt? datos con columnas , o datos de persona?, porque si ese es el caso deberías manejarlo con json , haces un archivo aparte y lo lee con javascript. Y otra cosa trata de poner el código que llevas siempre aca para que vean que haz hecho algo y te ayuden acá.Saludos.

Comment: el txt solo tiene texto sin ningun formato o secuencia especifica

Comment: EL txt puede solo tener un hola

Comment: ¿En la carpeta raíz de tu servidor o en la carpeta raíz del PC del usuario?

Comment: En la carpeta del servidor donde esta el html de la pagina

Comment: Y qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un objeto XMLHttpRequest para leer el archivo que tienes en el mismo directorio de tu pagina, pero si lo haces en local no podras probarlo con chrome porque te producira un error de Cross-origin resource sharing, puedes testearlo con internet explorar si no tienes ssl implementando en tu servidor, este es un ejemplo funcional:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var contenido_texto;
  var tu_variable;
  if(navigator.appName.search('Microsoft')>-1) { contenido_texto = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP'); }
  else { contenido_texto = new XMLHttpRequest(); }

  function leertxt() {
    contenido_texto.open('get', 'data1.txt', true); 
    contenido_texto.onreadystatechange = ver;
    contenido_texto.send(null);
    tu_variable = contenido_texto.responseText;

  }

  function ver() {
    if(contenido_texto.readyState==4) {
      document.getElementById('midiv').innerHTML = contenido_texto.responseText;
    }
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="leertxt();ver();">

  <div id="midiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No es posible cargar archivos de tu disco duro utilizando solamente el navegador, si quieres acceder a filesystem debes usar algo como Node.js por ejemplo.

Podrías montar tu archivo como json en `https://tudominio.com/archivo.json`, luego cargarlo con `window.fetch` cuando cargue tu página y luego modificar los datos de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

```
window.fetch('/archivo.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => /** manipular response **/ )
```

Answer (score 0):

Para esto debes de configurar un servidor local (si abres el index.html localmente recibiras un error Cross origin requests, por esto debe ser un servidor) con los siguientes archivos:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ejemplo.txt",
        context: document.body,
        crossDomain: true
    }).done(function (response) {
        //Datos de tu archivo en la variable response
        document.write(response);
    });
});
```

**ejemplo.txt**

```
Hola Mundo
```